# Onde armazenar os videos

Tags: php, mysql, html5

Opaz boa amigos. Bom eu desenvolvi um site de séries, onde vou postar filmes, séries etc. E o que eu tenho duvida é sobre onde ssera melhor para armazenar os videos sem que interfira no desempenho do site, eu deveria armazenar o video no banco de dados, ou na própria pasta do site?

Comment: o adequado seria você mover o arquivo de video para uma pasta e adicionar o caminho do video no banco.

Comment: usa o bucket de storage da amazon ou do google. he super barato c paga centavos por GB utilizado.

Comment: O que seria esse bucket?